# android studio folders inside packages

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-native-interface, package

how can I have a directory structure like

src/main/java/com.L33Tcode.example/Adapters

src/main/java/com.L33Tcode.example/Fragments

android studio doesn't seem to want to let me have source folders inside a package folder for some reason. Also if I want to have jni libraries and native c++ code how can I have this inside the same package. The android studio is a great program but the directory structure is really confusing please help. Right now my project doesn't even have a package folder and none of the source code has "package" at the top but it seems to find everything alright.

Comment: Packages and folders are the same thing, there should be no problem having two packages: com.LS33Tcode.example.adapters and com.LS33Tcode.example.fragments.

Comment: @Egor Thanks I was getting really confused , now I understand if you want to have different folders like I was trying to do you have to put them in different packages. I was trying to have nest regular folders into a single package which I guess isn't the proper way to do java. All the best!

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your package name(src/main/java/com.L33Tcode.example). After that select **New->Package** and enter folder name(Fragments) watever you want. Here you can see that your package is created. package in it's self is your folder. So, you can see it from right click on your **created folder(Fragments)-> show in history** and show your folder init.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the "Package" is the folder

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your `package` and select ***new > Package*** then name it `activity` or `fragment` or ...